# php exec returns error code as 1 while dynamically add the value

Tags: php, exec

i am trying to execute exec command in php.my code is

```
 $product=trim($_POST['prod']);
 $customer=trim($_POST['cust']);
 $mid=trim($_POST['id']);
 exec('cd C:\xampp\htdocs\AUDIT-TOOL\bat\Wrapper_Create_Product_Customer_Folder.bat '.$product.' '.$customer.' '.$mid.' 2>&1',$output, $return);
 if ($return != 0) {
   // error occurred
   echo $return;
   exit;
 }else{
     // success
    echo "successfully ";
 }
```

it always return 1 as error.and the error is
**System cannot find the path specified**

i tried following command in cmd that is working fine:

```
Wrapper_Create_Product_Customer_Folder.bat cookies britannia 01 2>&1
```

(but dynamically i need to pass cookies britannia 01 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, You are trying to change dir. Remove "cd" in command.

Comment: thanku.why cd is not working in this code.cd is for changing dir only right?